# Can you give me a short step by step numerical example of radial basis function kernel trick? I would like to understand how to apply on perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I understand well perceptron so put accent only on kernel but I am not familiar with matemathic expressions so please give me an numerical example and a guide on kernel.

**For example:**

My hyperplane of perceptron is `x1*w1+x2*w2+x3*w3+b=0;` The `RBF` kernel formula: `k(x,z) = exp((-|x-z|^2)/2*variance^2)` where takes action the radial basis function kernel here. Is `x` an input and what is `z` variable here?

Or of what I have to calculate variance if it is variance in the formula? 
Somewhere I have understood so that I have to plug this formula in perceptron  decision function `x1*w1+x2*w2+x3*w3+b=0;` but how does it look look like If I plug in?

I would like to ask a numerical example to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Linear Perceptron

As you know linear perceptrons can be trained for binary classification. More precisely, if there is `n` features, `x1, x2, ..., xn` in n-dimensional space, `Rn`, and you want to label them in 2 categories, `y1 & y2` (usually -1 and +1), you can use linear perceptron which defines a hyperplane `w1*x1 + ... + wn*xn + b = 0` to do so.

```
w1*x1 + ... + wn*xn + b > 0  or W.X + b > 0  ==>  class = y1
w1*x1 + ... + wn*xn + b < 0  or W.X + b < 0  ==>  class = y2
```

Linear perceptron will work well, only if the problem is linearly separable in `Rn`. For example, in 2D space, this means that one line can separate the 2 sets of points.

**Algorithm**

One common algorithm to train the perceptron, i.e., find weights and bias, `w's & b`, based on `N` data points, `X1, ..., XN`, and their labels, `Y1, ..., YN` is the following:

```
Initialize: W = zeros(n,1); b = 0
For i=1 to N:
    Calculate F(Xi) = W.Xi + b
    If F(Xi)*Yi <= 0:
        W <--- W + Xi*Yi
        b <--- b + Yi
```

This will give the final value for `W & b`. Besides, based on the training, `W` will be a linear combination of training points, `Xi's`, more precisely, the ones that were misclassified. So `W = a1*X1 + ... + ...aN*XN` where `a's` are in `{0,y1,y2}`.

Now, if there is a new point, let's say `Z`, to label, we check the sign of `F(Z) = W.Z + b = a1*(X1.Z) + ... + aN*(XN.Z) + b`. It is interesting that only the inner product of new point and training points take part in it.

#### Kernel Perceptron

Now, if the problem is not linearly separable, one may try to go to a higher dimensional space in which a hyperplane can do the classification. As an example, consider a circle in 2D space. The points inside and outside of the circle can't be separated by a line. However, if you find a transformation that can take the points to 3D space such that the first 2 coordinates remain the same for all points, and the 3rd coordinate become +1 and -1 for the points inside and outside of the circle respectively, then a plane defined as `3rd coordinate = 0` can separate the points.

Finding such transformations can be difficult and computationally heavy, so the kernel trick is introduced. Notice that we only used the inner product of new points with the training points. Kernel trick employs this fact and defines the inner product of the transformed points without actually finding the transformation.

If the unknown transformation is `P(X)` then Kernel function will be:
`K(Xi,Xj) = <P(Xi),P(Xj)>`. So instead of finding `P`, kernel functions are defined which represent the scalar result of the inner product in high-dimensional space. There are also theorems about what functions can be kernel functions, i.e., correspond to inner product in another space.

After choosing a kernel function, the algorithm will be modified as follows:

```
Initialize: F(X) = 0
For i=1 to N:
    Calculate F(Xi)
    If F(Xi)*Yi <= 0:
        F(.) <--- F(.) + K(.,Xi)*Yi + Yi
```

At the end, `F(.) = a1*K(.,X1) + ... + ...aN*K(.,XN) + b` where `a's` are in `{0,y1,y2}`.

#### RBF Kernel

Radial basis function is one type of kernel function that is actually computing the inner product in an infinite-dimensional space. It can be written as

```
K(Xi,Xj) = exp(- norm2(Xi-Xj)^2 / (2*sigma^2))
```

Sigma is some parameter that you can work with to find an optimum value for. For example, you can train the model with different values of sigma and then find the best value based on the performance. You can start with `sigma = 1`

After training the model to find `F(.)`, for a new data `Z`, the sign of `F(Z) = a1*K(Z,X1) + ... + ...aN*K(Z,XN) + b` will determine the class.

**Remarks:**

- Regarding to your question about variance, you don't need to find any variance.
- About `x and z` in your question, in each iteration, you should find the kernel output for the current data point and all the previously added points (the points that were misclassified and hence were added to `F`).
- I couldn't come up with a simple instructive numerical example.

References:
I borrowed some notation from
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVu-fXo8DOAhVDxCYKHQkcDDAQFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Falex.smola.org%2Fteaching%2Fpune2007%2Fpune_3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHlxy9TnY8xNe2-QDERipN_GycSqQ&bvm=bv.129422649,d.eWE

Comment: I am grateful for your help Mahsa Ghasemi. You have written a lot to demonstrate the kernel trick and I really appreciate that. I am not a programmer and how I said I am not familiar with matemathic expressions.

Comment: Mahsa Ghasemi - I also didn`t learn any algorithms or low level programming and have not bachelor degree in informatics but I have teached myself on some object programming language and could implement some machine learning algorithms but through hand computed examples and this way could understand very well. I don`t want to be obtrusive but please if you can help give me with an hand computed example with 2-3 iterations with radial basis function kernel.